# Why laravel helpers accessible from all namespaces?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, helper, autoloader

So far i see that there are two file with functions that loaded with composer autoloader.

```
 "autoload": {
         "files": [
             "src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php",
             "src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php"
        ],
```

And then in autoloader:

```
function composerRequire69685de7f834ebe45f1e02416f8679f0($fileIdentifier, $file)
{
    if (empty($GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier])) {
        require $file;

        $GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier] = true;
    }
}
```

But actually it just require this file, and all functions comes only to global namespace. Can you explain me why eventually all this functions are accessible from all namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why helpers works in all namespaces:

> For functions and constants, PHP will fall back to global functions
>   or constants if a namespaced function or constant does not exist.

[PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of composers psr-4 autoloading feature. 
in the files section of composers autoload you are defining the files it should autoload. So let's consider in one of the files you have function called "calculate". When you now call calculate composer knows in which files it finds the function. If you would remove the files from the autoloading the function call would stop working.

Comment: I know it. Composer autoload file is very simple consists of 70 lines of code, so i'm trying to understand how it works exactly.

Comment: You should checkout this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84j61_aI0q8